# Random text showing on JButton when changing background to translucent color

Tags: java, swing, background-color, opacity, visual-glitch

If I change my `JButton` to have a translucent color (0 < alpha < 1), I get wonky results for my `JButton` text.

```java
package Paint;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class GUI
{

   public GUI()
   {
   
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   
      frame.setTitle("Paint");
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   
      frame.add(createMainPanel());
   
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
      
      // System.out.println(JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose a color", null, true));
   
   }
   
   private static JPanel createMainPanel()
   {
   
      final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      
      final JPanel topPanel = GUI.createTopPanel();
      
      mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      
      return mainPanel;
   
   }
   
   private static JPanel createTopPanel()
   {
   
      final JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
      topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
      
      topPanel.add(GUI.createColorChooserPanel());
      
      return topPanel;
   
   }
   
   private static JPanel createColorChooserPanel()
   {
   
      final int NUM_ROWS = 3;
      final int NUM_COLUMNS = 3;
      final String DIALOG_TITLE = "Choose a color";
      final java.util.List<Character> KEY_LIST = 
         java.util.List.of('U', 'I', 'O', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'B', 'N', 'M');
   
      final JPanel colorChooserPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLUMNS));
      
      for (int index = 0; index < NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLUMNS; index++)
      {
      
         final JButton button = new JButton("" + KEY_LIST.get(index));
         button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(20.0f));
         button.setOpaque(true);
         button
            .addActionListener
            (
               event -> 
                  button
                     .setBackground
                     (
                        JColorChooser
                           .showDialog
                           (
                              button, 
                              DIALOG_TITLE, 
                              button.getBackground(), 
                              true
                           )
                     )
            );
      
         colorChooserPanel.add(button);
      
      }
      
      return colorChooserPanel;
   
   }

}
```

Click on the center button, select a color, go to RGB tab, change alpha to be within the above mentioned range, then click ok. Then, hover mouse all over the buttons rapidly. You should wonky results like garbled text.

Here's a few photos of the wonky results in action.

BEFORE

[image]

CLICKED ON THE CENTER BUTTON, THEN SELECTED A COLOR

[image]

CLICKED ON THE RGB TAB, THEN CHANGED THE ALPHA VALUE

[image]

CLICKED OK, AND NOW THE JBUTTON HAS A WONKY BACKGROUND

[image]

MORE

[image]

[image]

Moving my mouse between the center buttons and the other buttons seems to change the text of the center button.

**EDIT** - I am building a clone of Microsoft Paint, and this particular piece of functionality is to recreate the color chooser on the top right of the following screenshot. Like this.

[image]

I plan to use [`JColorChooser.showDialog(Component, String title, Color)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html#showDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.String,java.awt.Color)) as a popup for the user to select their color. But once they do, I want to bring that color back down to the component they clicked on (currently a `JButton`), so that they can see and select it next time.

**EDIT 2** - Here is what happens if I set `alpha` to be 0.

CHOOSING COLOR WITH `ALPHA` OF 0

[image]

THE RESULTS -- SAME PROBLEM, DIFFERENT SHADE OF COLOR

[image]

[image]

Comment: Swing components don’t support alpha based colors

Comment: Swing components are either fully opaque or fully transparent.  You can "fake" it, but you may not like the effect, as you will need to set the component to transparent (ie `setOpaque(false)`) and the override it's `paintComponent` method and paint the color yourself - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472993/weird-color-changes-on-hovering-on-jbutton/35473190#35473190)

Comment: @davidalayachew What is your objective in doing this? Do you want to be able to see a background image behind the buttons? Depending on your goal there are different ways to fake it, or use a completely different approach

Comment: @sorifiend I have edited my post to include my objective at the bottom.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for the information! I have edited my post to include context and intent. Perhaps `JLayer` would be a useful alternative? Overriding the `paintComponent` method isn't a deal breaker, but it would use up a decent chunk of my mental complexity budget when I am still very early on in this project.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you also link me to documentation from Oracle that says that they don't support translucent? I will remove the `visual-glitch` tag in response.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Actually, does it even support transparent? I tried making one of the colors with an `alpha` of 0, and it still gave me a visual glitch. Editing my post to demonstrate. EDIT - Ah, nevermind - you said `setOpaque`

Comment: Maybe [JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/) would be more suitable (rather than _Swing_)?

Comment: @Abra I sincerely doubt that. Swing has proven to be incredibly flexible for this exact use case. And I have already been given 2 very suitable approaches. I am only holding out for a simpler one. I have thrown out a third alternative involving `JLayer` which should be exactly as simple as I want, but awaiting a response.

Comment: For an alpha value of 0 you use setOpaque( false ). For other alpha values you can use the `AlphaContainer` as demonstrated in [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) so you don't have do custom painting all the time as demonstrated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3562529/131872.

Comment: @davidalayachew *"Swing components are either fully opaque or fully transparent"* - They do not support translucency or alpha based colors

Comment: @MadProgrammer This comment is a repeat of what you told me before. What is your intent in saying it?

Comment: @davidalayachew You said *"Actually, does it even support transparent?*" - but I'd already stated that *"Swing components are either fully opaque or fully transparent"* and wished the clarify the difference between "transparency" (see through) and "translucency" (partially see through - or, alpha base colors)

Comment: You may like to refer to https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/, which is in line with @MadProgrammer has talked about.

Comment: @camickr Thank you very much! Honestly, I think I'll just go with the solution that you and MadProgrammer have been saying. It's simple enough. Thank you both for the help!

Comment: @MadProgrammer Since I'm going with the solution you & camickr made, could you all close my question as a duplicate?

Comment: *I think I'll just go with the solution that you and MadProgrammer have been saying.* - actually our solutions are different. Madprogrammer's solution is to customize every component. Mine is to use a wrapper panel which does all the work so you don't have to customize each component. The explanation for the problem and the implementation in each class is basically the same.

Comment: @camickr Agreed, the internals are the same, but one is packaged into a type, while the other is an anonymous class for each call site.

Comment: @camickr btw, now that I am actually using your linked GitHub copy of the code, I think you are missing a call to `super.paintComponent(g);` in your `paintComponent` override. You have it in the SO post, but not the GitHub link on your T4J website.

Comment: @davidalayachew, The paintComponent() method is used to do the custom painting of the component. So yes, the general code, if you decide to extend each component manually, needs to invoke super.paintComponent() to invoke the custom painting logic of the component. However,  the `AlphaContainer` extends `JComponent` which has no custom painting.  You could add the statement. I decided to leave it out to indicate that there is no other special painting code needed for the container.

Comment: @camickr ty vm! Didn't realize that, that is very informative. I'm learning a lot from you 2 lately, ty both vm.